# How can I get recursively list an apt package's dependencies with their installed versions?

Tags: apt, package-management

I would like to list the recursive dependencies of a given package, with the **currently installed** version of each dependency. I'd also like one entry on each line, so it's sortable and diffable.

Basically, given, say, `tcpdump`, I would like the output to look like:

```
libtext-wrapi18n-perl: 0.06-7
perl-base: 5.14.2-21+deb7u2
```

...etc. The exact format of each line doesn't matter so much, just the ability to diff and sort.

The question [List (recursive) dependencies of the installed packages in APT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29653/list-recursive-dependencies-of-the-installed-packages-in-apt) is similar, but doesn't give package versions. Using `debfoster -d` looks promising, but its output does not lend itself to further processing.

Comment: I'm unclear what you want. I don't see any direct connection between `tcpdump` and `libtext-wrapi18n-perl` and `perl-base`. You write "recursively list a package's dependencies". Does that mean you want all the packages that "tcpdump" has a runtime dependency on? The immediate dependencies are given for example by `apt-cache show tcpdump`, and are `Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libpcap0.8 (>= 1.2.1), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)`. Or do you want the reverse dependencies of `tcpdump`, i.e. the packages that have a runtime dependency on `tcpdump`? This is given by `apt-cache rdepends tcpdump`.

Comment: You could also check out `apt-rdepends tcpdump` and `apt-rdepends -r tcpdump`. `apt-cache rdepends` seems kinda flakey; you might prefer `apt-rdepends`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I want all packages that `tcpdump` depends upon, and all of their dependencies, and all of their dependencies, etc.

Comment: @FaheemMitha FYI `apt-cache rdepends` shows *reverse* dependencies (aka. dependants). Very confusingly, it has a similar name to `apt-rdepends`, which shows recursive dependencies.

Comment: `apt-rdepends` show recursive dependencies. `apt-rdepends -r` shows reverse recursive dependencies. Doesn't. `apt-rdepends` work for you then?

Answer (score 6):

Both answers already provided have their pros and cons.

Starting with `debfoster` gives a list of packages which is simple to parse, so the following gives the requested result:

```
apt-cache policy $(debfoster -q -d tcpdump|tail -n +2)|awk '/^[^ ]/ { package=$0 } /  Installed/ { print package " " $2 }'
```

using `tail` to skip the first line and `awk` to process the result in a single operation. (Using a command substitution avoids the need to process newlines.) Starting with `debfoster` means we can only do this with a package which is already installed, so we can then use `dpkg` to provide more information:

```
dpkg -l $(debfoster -q -d tcpdump|tail -n +2)
```

Starting with `apt-rdepends` gives a list of packages which is a little harder to process, with duplicates; but it has the advantage of being able to process packages which aren't yet installed:

```
apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends -p tcpdump 2>| /dev/null|awk '/Depends/ {print $2}'|sort -u)|awk '/^[^ ]/ { package=$0 } /  Installed/ { print package " " $2 }'
```

This can also be used with `dpkg -l`:

```
dpkg -l $(apt-rdepends -p tcpdump 2>| /dev/null|awk '/Depends/ {print $2}'|sort -u)
```

but this requires that `dpkg` know about all the packages involved, which may not be the case if the package being processed isn't installed.

`debfoster` includes `Recommends` by default; this can be disabled using `--option UseRecommends=no`:

```
debfoster -q --option UseRecommends=no -d tcpdump
```

`apt-rdepends` doesn't include `Recommends` by default; this can be enabled using `-f Depends,PreDepends,Recommends -s Depends,PreDepends,Recommends`:

```
apt-rdepends -f Depends,PreDepends,Recommends -s Depends,PreDepends,Recommends -p tcpdump
```

although it doesn't give all the dependencies `debfoster` finds in that case. (For example `debfoster` finds that `tcpdump` depends on `apt` via `libssl1.0.0`, `debconf` and `apt-utils`, but `apt-rdepends` doesn't.)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that `tail` option! In my situation, I only care about installed packages, but the solutions for not-installed packages might prove useful too.

Answer (score 2):

The poster writes (in a comment):

> I want all packages that tcpdump depends upon, and all of their
>   dependencies, and all of their dependencies, etc.

[`apt-rdepends`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-rdepends) does this. NOTE: the "r" in "rdepends" means "recursive".

```
apt-rdepends -p tcpdump
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tcpdump
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) [Installed]
  Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.0.0) [Installed]
  Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) [NotInstalled]
libc6
  Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.3-4) [Installed]
  Depends: libgcc1 [Installed]
libc-bin
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-4.4-base (= 4.4.5-8) [NotInstalled]
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
gcc-4.4-base
libpcap0.8
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) [Installed]
libssl0.9.8
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) [Installed]
  Depends: debconf-2.0 [NotInstalled]
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) [Installed]
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) [Installed]
debconf
  Depends: debconf-english [NotInstalled]
  Depends: debconf-i18n [Installed]
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4) [Installed]
debconf-english
  Depends: debconf [Installed]
debconf-i18n
  Depends: debconf [Installed]
  Depends: liblocale-gettext-perl [Installed]
  Depends: libtext-charwidth-perl [Installed]
  Depends: libtext-iconv-perl [Installed]
  Depends: libtext-wrapi18n-perl [Installed]
liblocale-gettext-perl
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.10.0-25) [Installed]
  PreDepends: perlapi-5.10.0 [NotInstalled]
perl-base
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.20) [Installed]
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.4) [Installed]
dpkg
  PreDepends: coreutils (>= 5.93-1) [Installed]
  PreDepends: libbz2-1.0 [Installed]
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.6) [Installed]
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32) [Installed]
  PreDepends: xz-utils [Installed]
  PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) [Installed]
coreutils
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.11-1) [Installed]
  PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 2.4.41-1) [Installed]
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.6) [Installed]
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32) [Installed]
libacl1
  Depends: libattr1 (>= 2.4.41-1) [Installed]
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
libattr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
libselinux1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4) [Installed]
libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3) [Installed]
xz-utils
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.6) [Installed]
  Depends: liblzma2 (>= 5.0.0) [NotInstalled]
liblzma2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
zlib1g
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
perlapi-5.10.0
libtext-charwidth-perl
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
  Depends: perl-base (>= 5.10.0-13) [Installed]
  Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 [NotInstalled]
libtext-iconv-perl
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) [Installed]
  Depends: perl-base (>= 5.10.0-13) [Installed]
  Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 [NotInstalled]
libtext-wrapi18n-perl
  Depends: libtext-charwidth-perl [Installed]
debconf-2.0
```

Comment: Where are the version numbers for installed dependencies? How can I simply get each one, on a line, with this information?

Comment: `apt-rdepends` does not provide that information. The `-p` flag does give some information about the package. This is probably the best one can do with existing tools. To do better, you'll have to write a script or customize `apt-rdepends`. Feel free to file a wishlist bug on `apt-rdepends`.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this was downvoted.

Comment: Because it seems like you didn't really read the question. I explicitly mentioned "recursive dependencies" and "currently installed version" in the first sentence of the question. I also linked to a similar question, explaining the extra requirement with mine. This doesn't add anything that's not already answered elsewhere on this site (including the linked question).

Comment: @detly I see. First, as I explained, I think this answer is as good as you are going to get with existing tools. Second, you aren't going to improve your chances of getting an answer or increase the motivation of people who are trying to help you by downvoting them. And yes, I did read the question.

Comment: 1. There may be ways to get machine friendly output from these (or other) tools, which would allow for further, simple parsing on the command line. 2. I have submitted an edit so I can remove the downvote eventually.

Answer (score 2):

The following set of commands seems to do it:

```
debfoster -q -d tcpdump |
 sed -n '1!p' |
 tr -s ' ' |
 xargs |
 tr '\n' ' ' |
 xargs -I _ -d ' ' -n 1 sh -c "echo  _: \"\$(apt-cache policy _ | grep '  Installed: ' | sed -e 's/  Installed: //')\""
```

This uses:

- `debfoster` to print the (recursive) dependencies
- `sed` to remove the first line
- `tr` to collapse extra spaces
- `xargs` to trim leading and trailing space
- `tr` to remove the trailing newline
- `xargs` to:

  - `echo` the package name
  - use `apt-cache policy` to find the installed version (along with `grep` and `sed` to extract the version itself.

It produces:

```
apt-utils: 1.0.1ubuntu2.6
debconf: 1.5.51ubuntu2
debconf-i18n: 1.5.51ubuntu2
dpkg: 1.17.5ubuntu5.3
gcc-4.8-base: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
[...etc...]
```

If anyone can see a way to simplify this, let me know.