# How do I install Python in Linux with no Internet access?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, python, docker, deb

Part 1

I have CentOS with no Internet access.  I have a docker container based on Ubuntu. I want to install Python inside the Docker container.  I downloaded some .deb files for installing Python 2.7.  I tried to install them with apt-get.  But those commands required Internet access.  I used dpkg -i to install the packages.  I use `dpkg -i libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.6_8_amd64.deb`.  I then followed up with apt-get install -f.  I am prompted with a yes/no question about extra packages.  I chose Y.  I then received an error about not being able to reach some URLs.  This isn't surprising because the underlying server cannot get to the Internet.  The URLs refer to `python2.7-minimal_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb` among others.  I specifically have this .deb file.  But when I try to install it,  I get an error about an unmet dependency python2.7-minimal.  I am well aware that this was not installed.  I want it installed.

How do I install `python2.7-minimal_2.7.6-amd64.deb` in Docker?

Part 2

I tried to workaround the problem that I don't know how to solve.  I obtained Python-2.7.11.tar.xz.  It is 12 MB. In the Docker container, tried this:

```
tar xvf Python-2.7.11.tar.xz
```

But I get `tar (child): xz: connect exec: No such file or directory`

I verified the file exists.  In fact, when I type the command "tar xvf Python2.7" I can press tab to complete the full name of the file.  Is there a standalone file or other offline method for installing Python?

Final request:

Ideally I can get assistance for both parts even though only one needs to work.

Comment: Do you need to do it while blindfolded also?

Comment: The easy thing to do might be to set up the docker container elsewhere and move over the whole image. I wouldn't replace python that way too - there's a reasonble risk you may break something. Also, that's an xz compressed file and needs another application for it

Answer (score 2):

The cache solution in Mark Smith's answer is a great idea; I've done that succesfully.

Another solution, having on my machine internet connection and SSH connection to the VM's is:
Install a proxy (squid) on my machine that has SSH connection to the firewalled VM's.
Declare on the firewalled VM's a local proxy 127.0.0.1:3128 and make an SSH tunnel from that port to my own machine's port.

This way you can install, update, and patch dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to do this (albeit with different packages, not Python) a few times on build machines which are not allowed to see the Internet and are in a different part of the building to my Internet-connected machine.  It's a bit of a pain.

There are ways to recursively list the dependencies of a given package (some given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188964/how-can-i-get-recursively-list-an-apt-packages-dependencies-with-their-installe)), so that you can download them all in one go, and minimise the to-ing and fro-ing, but in reality I find the following easier:

- Install the same OS in a virtual machine which CAN see the internet.
- Install what you need onto it.
- Copy `/var/cache/apt/archives/*` to a CD (or however you move the stuff to this machine) and then you'll have everything you need.  Either copy it all into `/var/cache/apt/archives` on your target machine, or if you're trying to keep it minimal, do them one at a time as you need them.